# Xcode getting a Command CodeSign failed with nonzero exit code: APP is a directory

Tags: swift, xcode

```
/Users/user/Desktop/APPNAME/DerivedData/APPNAME/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app: Is a directory Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Getting this error after I accidentally removed the main build folder for the target and then added it back to the target. I have already tried deleting derived data and clean building the project and I am pretty stuck on what I can try next.